# How to disable headshot sound in CSGO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When my character gets a headshot the volume of this is way too loud. I want to disable this headshot sound entirely or make it much more quiet. Is this possible?

Comment: sad there doesn't seem to be a solution 2 years later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as it currently stands there is no way of doing this. Modifying the volume of a single sound is not possible.

What you could do is changing the sound file in the game's vpk file, but that will get you blocked from pure servers, so you would only be able to join custom servers, which don't use `sv_pure 1`.

Comment: That's such a pity. I wish developers could provide a client option to disable this terribly loud headshot sound.

Comment: user7634: amen to this

Comment: This includes getting shot in the head, which I've always found to be an issue (rather that *getting* a headshot)?

Comment: @user598527 yes, the primary issue is taking a headshot. Scoring one is not the problem.